# react props values defined (with visible sub prop values), but sub prop values are undefined

Tags: reactjs, undefined, render, react-props

i'm able to access `(this.)props.somePropValue` and see its subcontents, but when accessing `(this.)props.somePropValue.subContents`, this returns as UNDEFINED

```
(this.)props.somePropValue = {
    id: 012345,
    subArray: []
}

const SomeComponent = (props) => {

    // somePropValue defined here & subArray IS VISIBLE inside somePropValue
    console.log(props.somePropValue)

    // subArray UNDEFINED here
    console.log(props.somePropValue.subArray)

    return (
        <div />
    )
}
```

Comment: this seems like a good starting point: https://medium.com/@chekofif/using-es6-s-proxy-for-safe-object-property-access-f42fa4380b2c

Answer (score 0):

solution is to be able to access deeply nested values in JS objects

looks like [ramda](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#path) has this functionality covered with `R.path()`

[image]